# Creating SBT task to copy directories during compile?

Tags: hibernate, scala, sbt

I'm new to the whole SBT and Scala scene and am trying to build a project that uses Java/Scala classes and Hibernate.  I'm getting the project to build fine -- I just have to manually copy over my hibernate config files to my `target/scala<version>/classes` folder so they can be picked up by hibernate.

Is there a way to create a task in SBT to copy these folders over on each compile? This is my `Build.scala` file:

```
import sbt._

object Sportsbook extends Build {
  lazy val project = Project (
    "sportsbook",
    file("."),
    copyConfigTask
  )

  val copyConfig = TaskKey[Unit]("copy", "Copy hibernate files over to target directory")

  /*
  // Something like this
  lazy val copyConfigTask = copyConfig <<=
    val configDir1 = baseDirectory / "config"
    val configDir2 = outputPath / "config"
    IO.copyDirectory(configDir1, configDir2)
  */
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The most direct means to achieve this is to move the files into `./src/main/resources/config`.

Alternatively, add `${base}/config` to `resourceDirectories in Compile`.

```
resourceDirectories in Compile <+= baseDirectory / "config"
```

Unfortunately, files in there will be copied to the root of the classpath. You would need to move them to `./src/config/config` to restore that. (See how the `mappings` for resources are [based on the relative location of resource files to the base resource directories](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/blob/v0.11.0/main/Defaults.scala#L502))

Do you want the files packaged in your JAR? Both of these answers would result in that. You could take them out of `mappings in packageBin` to avoid this.

```
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ~= (_.filter { case (file, outpath) => outpath.startsWith("/config")} )
```

Comment: Thanks -- I just went with the first. For some reason I was linking in my head resources with only jar files. Much simpler this way.

Comment: @user988427 could you approve the answer since it's worked for you?